# Attempting to get the response from a TimeItem on my google form?

Tags: forms, time, response

When I use getResponse(), it returns a string that doesn't even have the AM or PM value. Thus I cannot use the Date and Time functions on the response. Does someone know how to get my timeItem response to save properly.

I do know that I need to create a Date object in order to use the date and time functions. That's not the problem.

var tester = Responses[3].getResponseForItem(Items[7]).getResponse();

It returns at string like "3:00" when I would rather it return something like "3:00PM"

Answer (score 0):

The TimeItem class is defined on the 24-hour clock.  I don't think they explicitly provide AM and PM tags.  Note, this is also the case with DateTimeItems.

**Documenation:** [TimeItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/time-item)

If you want the string to be 3:00PM/AM instead of 3:00, write a short conditional statement.

**Something like:**

```
if(timeItem > 12:00 AND timeItem < 23){
  tester = tester + "PM";
} else {
  tester = tester + "AM";
}
```